# Move to next selection in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

When I have multiple selections in a Word 2007 document, such as after selecting all instances of a style, how can I move from one selection to the next? When you issue the select all instances command, the view snaps to the next instance of the style, but how can I find the other instances? Any cursor key will unselect everything. Using the mouse to scroll through the document is not feasible for large documents, plus the selection could be a single character -- very easy to miss!

Comment: I've tried everything and I think it is not possible. I hope someone gives you a more useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Sergio Acosta. There doesn't seem to be any way to scroll through the selected instances.

However, you can search for the style.

- Press Ctrl-F or click Find on the Home ribbon (Word 2007)
- leave the search text (Find What) blank
- click the More button
- click the Format button and select Style
- choose the style you want and click OK
- click Find Next

If you close the Find dialog, you can use Ctrl + PgDn to search for the next occurrence or Ctrl + PgUp to search for the previous one. This is very handy when repeating searches to make multiple edits.

Don't forget to clear the format selection the next time you search (click No Formatting in the Find dialog) or you'll only be searching within the text that has a particular style. This is also useful, but often not what you want.

Comment: Ack! Tunnel-vision strikes again. Find styles does exactly what I needed.